# How do I construct an object of a slice struct?

Tags: go, struct, slice, literals

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)
type demo []struct {
    Text string
    Type string
}
func main() {
    
    d := demo{
        Text: "Hello",
        Type: "string",
    }
    
}
```

In this code I'm getting an error while declaring the object of `demo` struct:

> ./prog.go:11:3: undefined: Text
> ./prog.go:11:9: cannot use "Hello" (untyped string constant) as struct{Text string; Type string} value in array or slice literal
> ./prog.go:12:3: undefined: Type
> ./prog.go:12:9: cannot use "string" (untyped string constant) as struct{Text string; Type string} value in array or slice literal

it's obvious because it is not a normal struct declaration so please help me how can I construct object of `demo` struct?

Comment: It's because your type is a slice of structs, but you're creating `d` as a single struct. Do you want the `demo` type to be a single struct or a slice of them?

Comment: Don’t use a slice of anonymous structs as a type, just declare the struct you want and create a slice if you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you declared `demo` as a slice of anonymous structs, you have to use `demo{}` to construct the slice and `{Text: "Hello", Type: "string"}` to construct the item(s).

```
func main() {
    d := demo{{
        Text: "Hello",
        Type: "Anon",
    }}

    fmt.Println(d)
    // [{Hello Anon}]
}
```

Being a slice, you can also `make` it, but then appending items requires replicating the definition of the anonymous struct:

```
func main()
    d1 := make(demo, 0)
    d1 = append(d1, struct {
        Text string
        Type string
    }{"Hello", "Append"})

    fmt.Println(d1)
    // [{Hello Append}]
}
```

However albeit it compiles, it is rather uncommon. Just define the named struct type, and then `d` as a slice of those. The syntax is almost the same, but straightforward:

```
// just defined struct type
type demo struct {
    Text string
    Type string
}

func main() {
    
    d2 := []demo{{
        Text: "Hello",
        Type: "Slice",
    }}
    fmt.Println(d2)
    // [{Hello Slice}]
}
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/4kSXqYKEhst